# how can I add animation time to css changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Is it possible to add a duration of a css change so that when I change the left, top, width and height of a div this could be animated?

In the jQuery code I want to animate the duration of the css properties.

Thanks a lot if you could help me, Its appreciated!

My code

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img class="image1" src="images/car1.jpg"></img>
    <img class="image2" src="images/car2.jpg"></img>
    <img class="image3" src="images/car3.jpg"></img>
    <img class="image4" src="images/car4.jpg"></img>
    <img class="image5" src="images/car5.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshowshadow{
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.2;
    margin: 50px 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 15px yellow;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 15px rgba yellow;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 15px yellow;
}

#slideshow{
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#slideshow img{
    color: white;
}

.image2, .image3, .image4, .image5{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

.image1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    height: 250px;
    top: 175px;
    left: 225px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.image2{
    top: 0px;
    left: 250px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.image3{
    top: 200px;
    left: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.image4{
    top: 400px;
    left: 250px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.image5{
    top: 200px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

JQUERY (This is where the magic happens :p):

```
$(".image2").click(function(){

        $(".image1").css("top", "0px");
        $(".image1").css("left", "250px");
        $(".image1").css("width", "300px");
        $(".image1").css("height", "200px");
        $(".image1").css("z-index", "1");

        //middle
        $(".image2").css("top", "175px");
        $(".image2").css("left", "225px");
        $(".image2").css("width", "350px");
        $(".image2").css("height", "250px");
        $(".image2").css("z-index", "2");

        $(".image3").css("top", "200px");
        $(".image3").css("left", "500px");
        $(".image3").css("width", "300px");
        $(".image3").css("height", "200px");
        $(".image3").css("z-index", "1");

        $(".image4").css("top", "400px");
        $(".image4").css("left", "250px");
        $(".image4").css("width", "300px");
        $(".image4").css("height", "200px");
        $(".image4").css("z-index", "1");

        $(".image5").css("top", "200px");
        $(".image5").css("left", "0px");
        $(".image5").css("width", "300px");
        $(".image5").css("height", "200px");
        $(".image5").css("z-index", "1");
    });
```

Comment: it is always good to submit fiddle of your question :  http://jsfiddle.net/y43WR/

Comment: Have you looked at [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) or [transition:](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) yet? In not 100% clear on what you're trying to accomplish with the animation.

Answer (score 1):

You should either use animate where 5000 is the time in milliseconds.

```
$( ".image5" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "25px"
    // css goes here, last one should not have comma
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```

Or to use CSS animations, set the CSS transition time via jQuery:

```
var time = 5000

$('.image5').css({
    'webkitTransition': 'all ' + time + 's ',
    'mozTransition': 'all ' + time + 's ',
    'msTransition': 'all ' + time + 's ',
    'oTransition': 'all ' + time + 's ',
    'transition': 'all ' + time + 's '
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot I now know what to do, I changed the .css to .animate and changed the syntax a little bit and then I could add the timing :) Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you looking for:

```
transition-duration
```

see: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition-duration/ for further details